# Young’s inequality implies $a^ {n/(n+1)}\leq 2a+(1/n^2)$ for any $a>0$ and $n\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, extrapolation, young-inequality

I’ve seen this statement in a Yano’s article and  I can not prove it. I take the Young’s inequality
$a^{1/p}b^{1/q} \leq a/p + b/q$ where $1/p +1/q =1$. I’ve prove it in the case $a\geq 1$.
In the case where $n=1$ you can deduce it inmediatly from the Young’s inequality but in other cases I can not see the proof.

Comment: You can find the proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: For $a \ge 1$ you have $a^{n/(n+1)} \le a \le 2a \le 2a + 1/n^2$ even without Young's inequality.

Comment: This is true, but the problem remains unsolved for $a<1$…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to find a “suitable” real number $c > 0$ such that the application of Young's inequality to
$$
a^{n/(n+1)} = (ca)^{n/(n+1)} \, \cdot \, (1/c^n)^{1/(n+1)} 
\le \frac{n}{n+1} ca + \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{c^n}
$$
gives the term $2a$ as the first summand on the right-hand side.

This is the case for $c=\frac{2(n+1)}{n}$, so that we have
$$ \tag{*}
a^{n/(n+1)} \le 2a + \frac{1}{n+1}\left( \frac{n}{2(n+1)}\right)^n \, .
$$
That is stronger than the desired estimate because
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}\left( \frac{n}{2(n+1)}\right)^n
<  \frac{1}{(n +1) 2^n} < \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{1}{n^2} \, .
$$

---

An alternative is to observe that for fixed $n$ the function $f(a) = a^{n/(n+1)}$ is *concave,* so that we have
$$
 f(a) \le f(b) + (a-b)f'(b) \quad \text{for all } a, b > 0 \, .
$$
Choosing $b$ such that $f'(b) = 2$ gives again the inequality $(*)$.